# How to drop old values and get the latest?

Tags: swift, combine

The use of this combine pipeline is to search for a country. Everything works, but I would like to drop all items in the stream and get the latest text from the user, which should be coming from text field.

In Kotlin, there is `getLastest`. Is there anything similar when using Combine?

```swift
class Foo: ObservableObject {

  @Published var searchText = String()
  @Published var countries = [Country]()
  let allCountries: [Country] = [.init(name: "France"), .init(name: "Paraguay")]

  init() {
    $searchText
      .map { [weak self] text in

        let value = text.isEmpty
          ? self?.allCountries
          : self?.allCountries.filter { $0.name.contains(text) }

        return value ?? []
      }
      .assign(to: &$countries)
  }
}

struct Country {
  var name: String
}
```

Comment: I guess there's no such thing as "latest" in case of the search text publisher, because its `Failure` associated type is `Never`. You get a new value each time the text changes, but the publisher never finishes, so every value you receive is "latest". What you probably want here is a `debounce` operator that emits a single value once the user stopped typing for a given time interval.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev just wanted to cancel the filter on new works

Comment: not sure if I get it, can you elaborate?

Comment: you already help thank you